# ionic locally stored video dont work on android

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with playing videos which are locally stored inside ionic app. I think I tried every possible solution without success. So I decided to ask here. I will try to describe how is my app built.

My root folder is: `/myApp/www/`

In the index.html inside body tag I have only ion-nav-view tag pair. Im using 3 templates stored in:

```
/views/homepage.html
/views/sights/list.html
/views/sights/detail.html
```

Inside `/js/app.js` I have controllers for each template and until here everthing works fine.

Inside `/views/sights/detail.html` Im using video tag:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video controls="controls">
        <source ng-src="/video/vid01.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

I have this set:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ....> inside AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Other src paths I tried:

```
file:///video/vid01.mp4
file:///android_asset/www/video/vid01.mp4
file:///mnt/sdcard/media/video/vid01.mp4
```

But this works:

```
http://someserver.com/somevideo.mp4
```

Unfortunately this is not an option for me. The app will be used in place without any internet conenction so I need to have videos inside app.

Locally stored videos working fine only if I run my app from cmd: `ionic serve`.

When I try to deploy app on Android (4.4.4 kitkat) like: `ionic run android` everything works fine but video refuses to play.

I think I tried literally everything. Unfortunately all tutorials on how to play video in ionic app are made with online videos and those examples work only in browser not on Android devices.

Comment: The issue may be with the fragmented and outdated android web view, for any ionic or hyrbid app on android i highly recommend using the crosswalk web engine builtin into the app.  https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: Hi, **you are right**. I added crosswalk into my existing ionic app like this: `ionic browser add crosswalk` and **IT WORKS** with this src: `/android_asset/www/video/vid.mp4`. For all with same problem more info about crosswalk for ionic is here: [blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/).  Thank you very much for your help Jess

Comment: What is about local downloaded video files (to `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory`), how can I access them?

Comment: @Xover any success with local downloaded video files?

Answer (score 0):

**cross walk solved my problem**
cross walk make me able to use `<video>` tag in ionic application which is not allowed by default

it is about ionic 1.x

example code: https://github.com/malikasinger1/ionic-video-player