# How to play local video in ionic app <video> tag is not working

Tags: angularjs, video, ionic-framework, html5-video, ngcordova

**in ionic app**

**i am unable to play video from my project folder...**

i'm trying to make an app with 3 to 4 static videos which will play on device without internet connection

but i unable to do this

```
<div class="modal transparent full screen-player" ng-click="closeModal()">
    <video ng-src="img/test.mp4" class="centerme" controls="controls" autoplay> 
    </video>
</div>
```

currently i'm using this code,

video is playing very fine on `ionic serve` with this code but when i compile to `.apk` file by `ionic build android` or `ionic run android` this code stop working on device... a video player is appearing on device but not play video..

there is no error in chrome://inspect

i have also tried `$cordovaMedia` http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/

but this is not for playing video i think its documentation only showing examples for audios

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095528/ionic-locally-stored-video-dont-work-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cross walk solved my problem**
cross walk make me able to use `<video>` tag in ionic application which is not allowed by default

it is about ionic 1

example code: https://github.com/malikasinger1/ionic-video-player

Answer (score 0):

make the local server of the folder if you want to access file for mobile

below link will give a clear explanation of how to do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57494421/7456041