# How to save in local the translation file (after download) in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, translation

I need to download the translation file from a remote server and to save it in local to not download this one each time the app is reloading.

The file is downloaded but i can't save it.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

...

constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {
    }

    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {

            this.http.post(SERVER_BASE_URL, null, {headers: this.contentHeader}).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                    console.log('get translation from server');
                    console.log(res);
                     this.storage.set("test", res).then(response => {
                         console.log("save translation");
                     }).catch(error => {
                         console.log("error");
                         console.log(error);
                     })
                    observer.next(res);
                    observer.complete();
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('get translation from local');
                    //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                    this.http.get('/assets/i18n/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) => {
                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
                });
        });
    }
```

I have tried to use Storage but, i have the error 
"Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"

I have use the storage in other part of my app and it's work. So I don't understand why in the translationService it's not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try to save the file in local, i have the same error: Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined.

```
this.http.post(apiAddress, body, {headers: this.contentHeader}).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                        console.log('get translation from server');
                        console.log(res);

                        this.file.writeFile(
                            this.file.dataDirectory,
                            lang + '.json',
                            JSON.stringify(res),
                            {replace: true}).then(_ => {
                            console.log('Directory exists');
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log('Directory doesn\'t exist');
                        });

                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log('get translation from local');
                        //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                        this.http.get('/assets/i18n/' + lang + '.json').subscribe((res: Response) => {
                            observer.next(res);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                    });
```

I found what i have missed. In app.module.ts, i need to add "deps" to use the dependencies...

```
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            // useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            useClass: TranslationService,
            deps: [HttpClient, File]
        }
    }),
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store object or list then

```
this.storage.set('test', JSON.stringify(this.res));
```

while fetch

```
this.storage.get('test').then(value => {
          let res = JSON.parse(value);
      }).catch(err=>{
   console.log(err)
})
```

if you want to save the file then
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497397/7456041

Comment: Thanks for your response, but storage work on other pages and services. I have try with File but same error : Cannot read property 'writeFile' of undefined. I have import : import {File} from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';